# Hiding side nav overlay when router-link is clicked

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I have the following sidebar in my App.vue ionic app

I have this code in my App.vue that displays the side nav

```
<template>
  <IonApp>
    <IonSplitPane content-id="main-content">
      <ion-menu content-id="main-content"  type="overlay">
        <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar >
  
  <ion-grid class="top_header_section">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3" offset="2">
           <ion-img class="app_logo" :src="require('@/assets/improved_logo.png')"></ion-img>
        </ion-col>
         <ion-col size="2" offset="2">
           <ion-button class="small_button" color="tertiary"><ion-icon :icon="cartOutline"></ion-icon> Sell</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   
</ion-grid>


  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

        <ion-content>


      <ion-list class="no_margin_top">
        <ion-item button  router-link="/trending">
         <ion-icon :icon="flameOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Trending</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  @click="hideMenu" button router-link="/vehicles">
        <ion-icon :icon="carSportOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Vehicles</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item button router-link="/property">
         <ion-icon :icon="businessOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Property</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item button router-link="/phones">
         <ion-icon :icon="phonePortraitOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Phones & Tablets</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item button router-link="/electronics">
         <ion-icon :icon="headsetOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Electronics</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item button router-link="/homegarden">
         <ion-icon :icon="leafOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Home & Garden</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/healthbeauty">
        <ion-icon :icon="medkitOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Health & Beauty</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/fashion">
        <ion-icon :icon="colorPaletteOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Fashion</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item button router-link="/hobbies">
       <ion-icon :icon="americanFootballOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Hobbies,Art & Sports</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/cvs">
        <ion-icon :icon="documentTextOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Seeking Work CVs</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/services">
        <ion-icon :icon="listOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Services</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/jobs">
        <ion-icon :icon="documentAttachOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Jobs</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/babies">
        <ion-icon :icon="happyOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Babies & Kids</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/animals">
        <ion-icon :icon="fishOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Animals & Pets</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/agriculture">
        <ion-icon :icon="fastFoodOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Agriculture & Food</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item button router-link="/equipment">
       <ion-icon :icon="constructOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Equipment & Tools</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/repair">
        <ion-icon :icon="extensionPuzzleOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Repair & Construction</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/businesses">
        <ion-icon :icon="cashOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Businesses On Sale</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item button router-link="/hotels">
        <ion-icon :icon="bedOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Hotel & Accomondation</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="no_big_space_bottom" lines="none" button router-link="/logout">
        <ion-icon :icon="powerOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Logout</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer  class="bottom_footer_section">
    <ion-toolbar class="">
  <ion-grid class="">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-title class="ion-text-center">All Rights Reserved.</ion-title>
        </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>


  
      </ion-menu>
      <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
  </IonApp>
</template>
```

How can i hide the entire sidenav when this link is clicked

```
<ion-item button  router-link="/trending">
         <ion-icon :icon="flameOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Trending</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hide the side nav like this

```
<ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item  button router-link="/vehicles">
        <ion-icon :icon="carSportOutline"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Vehicles</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
   </ion-menu-toggle>
```